# Imprimir dados de uma tabela usando JSON

Tags: php, json

Bom dia a todos!
Pessoal, estou na seguinte dificuldade: Em meu sistema web possuo uma tabela, onde irei imprimi-la em uma impressora termina não fiscal. Está funcionando perfeitamente em Computadores e Notebooks. Em tabletes e Smartfones a UNICA função que não funciona é a de impressão. A função funciona em determinados aparelhos e marcas e versões do android, e quando funciona, imprime apenas uma única vez. Em pesquisa, me deparei com uma dica de um colega me orientando a fazer essa impressão via JSON no celular, porem estou super perdido. Ja dei uma olhada aqui mas não vem na minha cabeça uma forma de fazer. Gostaria, se possível que se alguém pudesse me dar uma força nisso, agradeceria muito.

Comment: "Imprimir dados de uma tabela usando JSON", você quer dizer na tela?

Comment: Não @rray, falo numa folha mesmo, usando impressora térmica não-fiscal.

Comment: Sobre o json comentado, entendi que seu colega falou, acesse o sistema pela celular pegue as informações do json e imprima a folha usando o celular, pois o php é uma linguagem side server ou seja ele não pode/deve acessar recursos locais(impressora). Agora acredito que seja possível configurar um impressora no celular, claro isso depende do tipo de porta(usb, serial etc) que ela usa.

Comment: Essa é a grande questão @rray. O que acontece é o seguinte: Possuo a impressora portátil DPP-350BT (conexão via Bluetooth), que é facilmente instalada. A questão é que em alguns dispositivos, a opção "imprimi" aparece nos navegadores moveis, e em outros não, e nos que aparecem, funcionam apenas a primeira vez, e pra funcionar novamente, só desempareando a impressora e pareando de novo pra poder funcionar. Ai o que eu não sei é se é uma questão de impressora, ou de sistema realmente

Comment: Quem show, essa impressoa bluetooth :D. Se você puder fazer o teste com celulares de marcas diferentes o resultado pode  variar.

Comment: É muito massa essa impressora mesmo! :D

Comment: Aí vê, testei em Motorola, Asus, Samsung e os resultados variaram muito. Provavelmente pode ser uma questão de compatibilidade do que de código, pq se fosse código, ela n funcionaria nenhuma vez, concorda? @rray?